# MNIST dataset boosting

Tags: classification, mnist, boosting

I am trying to apply Gradient Boosting to the MNIST dataset. This is my code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(caret)
mnist <- snedata::download_mnist()
mnist_num <- as.data.frame(lapply(mnist[1:10000,], as.numeric)) %>%
mutate(id = row_number())
mnist_num <- mnist_num[,sapply(mnist_num, function(x){max(x) - min(x) > 0})]

mnist_train <- sample_frac(mnist_num, .70)
mnist_test <- anti_join(mnist_num, mnist_train, by = 'id')

set.seed(5000)
library(gbm)
boost_mnist<-gbm(Label~ .,data=mnist_train, distribution="bernoulli", n.trees=70, 
interaction.depth=4, shrinkage=0.3)
```

It shows the following error:

"Error in gbm.fit(x = x, y = y, offset = offset, distribution = distribution, : Bernoulli requires the response to be in {0,1}"

What is wrong here? Can anyone show me the code to correctly do it?

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
Error in gbm.fit(x = x, y = y, offset = offset, distribution = distribution, : Bernoulli requires the response to be in {0,1}
```

is due to the choice of the distribution, you should choose the `multinomial` instead of the `bernoulli`, because the bernoulli distribution only works with dichotomous response and the `mnist` label goes from 1 to 10.